# rails4, simple_form, check_box, radio_button, controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have generated a model using scaffolding.

```
rails g scaffold attendance ename:string entertime:datetime sl:boolean mrgsl:boolean evesl:boolean halfday:boolean
```

now i want to show this using simple_form, and i want to make these relationships between them:

> sl--> has two types i) mrgsl. ii) evesl.

so when sl (check_box) is chosen it then show two radio_buttons and either of two is selected. 
and halfday is also a check_box.

```
<%= simple_form_for @attendance, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= f.input :ename %>
<%= f.input :entertime, as: :time %>
<%= f.input :sl, as: :check_box %>
<%= f.input :mrgsl, as: :radio_button %>
<%= f.input :evesl, as: :radio_button %>
<%= f.input :halfday, as: :check_box %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='col-md-offset-2 col-md-10'>
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                  attendances_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

this is how im trying to do it but it doesnot work,.

```
RuntimeError in Attendances#new

Showing /home/pallavsharma/Workspace/crm/app/views/attendances/_form.html.erb where line #4 raised:

No input found for check_box

1<%= simple_form_for @attendance, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
2<%= f.input :ename %>
3<%= f.input :entertime, as: :time %>
4<%= f.input :sl, as: :check_box %>
5<%= f.input :mrgsl, as: :radio_button %>
6<%= f.input :evesl, as: :radio_button %>
7<%= f.input :halfday, as: :check_box %>
```

what are the possible ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

First, if I understood correctly what you wrote, you may want to re-build your model to fit your logic better.

You want to give the user three options :

> "no ls" 
>   "ls with mrgsl" 
>   "ls with evesl"

Your model, with these booleans, says they have 8. But you don't want them to pick **mrgsl** if they haven't picked **ls** and you don't want them to pick **mrgsl** AND **evesl**, am I right ?

It would make more sense ( and make your code a lot easier to maintain ) if you don't have to re-migrate your database each time you want to add a new option to your "ls". So, I was thinking about making "ls " a string-type data in your model. Then you can give it whatever value you want : "evesl", "mrgsl", "disabled" and, later, add some more without any difficulty. 
You can then handle this in your controller. You won't be doing

```
Attendance.where(mrgsl: true)
```

but

```
Attendance.where(ls: "msgrl")
```

Anyway, to answer your question :in order to do what you want ( make your radio button appear if the checkbox is checked ) you'll need to write some JavaScript.

You can find everything in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322444/show-rest-of-a-form-if-a-checkbox-is-ckecked-in-ruby-on-rails) to make it work the way you want.

Finally, to use a bit of the simple_form power, you can make a ["collection"](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections) for your radio buttons.

Hope it helps !

Comment: what i basically need is, when user select sl(short leave) (check_box) then it show two radio_buttons (mrgsl and evesl) then user can select one of them as well.