# insert specifics js in the header of some pages - active admin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts, activeadmin, head

I use active admin and in my app there are different .js that must be loaded in specifics pages (not all).

Following this topic [Best way to add page specific javascript in a Rails 3 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437585/best-way-to-add-page-specific-javascript-in-a-rails-3-app?answertab=votes#tab-top) it appears to be easy, but the layout in active admin is compiled.

I have used a workaround to overwrite the footer:

```
    class ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base < Arbre::HTML::Document
 private
  # Renders the content for the footer
  def build_footer
    div :id => "footer" do
      para "Copyright &copy; #{Date.today.year.to_s}- All rights reserved ".html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

How can I add some .js in the header of some pages? How with a workaround? (if possible with a "yield :head" or something like that, so I can call it easier from everywhere ;))

EDIT NOTE: the js that i want to include render a highcharts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm using master branch of ActiveAdmin 0.5.0 (as of 23 Nov 2012) and there is a Arbre builder method `within` which is working for me.

```
show do 
   within @head do
      script :src => javascript_path('somefile.js'), :type => "text/javascript"
   end
end
```

You can see an example of its use in `ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base#build_active_admin_head`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will try in the next days, do you have any urls of how "Arbre builder" works? (or where have you find this information)

Comment: I think I just searched the Arbre source code for things like 'javascript'.

Answer (score 1):

I found an "alternative" solution, the basic one: insert simply the script in the html body with the jquery tag $(document).ready(...) (but with lose in performance and dry coding)