# Rails asset pipeline how to link to a specific .js file on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

So I have a view which basicaly loads in a given .js file and it works fine on local host but when i push it to heroku it dies.

basically in the controller i define

> @script = '/assests/script_name.js?body=1'

and in the view i call

> %script{:src => @script, :type => "text/javascript"}

and this loads the correct scripts in development but in production it can't find them

what am i missing?

Comment: On Heroku, **/public** is read-only, that may have something to do with your issue.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437585/best-way-to-add-page-specific-javascript-in-a-rails-3-app

Comment: Do you precompile your assets?

Comment: you've also spelled '/assests' wrong. it should be '/assets'.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller...

```
@script = view_context.asset_path('script_name.js')
```

If it was me, I'd do this instead though:

controller: `@script = 'script_name'`

view: `= javascript_include_tag @script`