# Why write modular javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, coding-style, modularity

The benefits of well-factored and modular code, in my understanding are re-usability and organization. Code written in a big chunk all in one file is difficult to read, and re-using small portions of the code requires careful copy-pasting, rather than include statements.

In particular, with regards to Javascript, I came across an example recently that got me thinking about this. A comment was made on SO to the effect that, if you are not including your javascripts conditionally on a page-by-page basis, this "represents a failure to modularize JS code properly". However, from a code re-use and organization point of view, there is no reason to consider what happens at page load time. The code will be just as readable if it is written in a bunch of separate files and then mashed together and minified before being served. The [rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), for example, does just this.

When I first encountered the asset pipeline, my mind reeled and I started wondering "how do I make javascripts load only when needed?" I read [a few SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437585/best-way-to-add-page-specific-javascript-in-a-rails-3-app) and [an article on the matter](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-javascript-include-external.html), and began to think that maybe I shouldn't worry about what happens to my code after it "compiles".

Is the purpose of writing modular code purely a human-level activity, should we stop worrying about modularity after the code starts running? In the case of Javascript, should we be concerned that our scripts are being mashed together before being included?

Comment: Imagine that minification is compilation. Would any developer *ever* care if their modular code isn't modular after compilation? No. Same applies to JavaScript. As for loading when needed, that depends very much on your use case. If the code is likely to be needed, it should be loaded. If it's unlikely to be needed, there may be benefit in loading it only when it is.

Comment: @Dave That's what I thought, but it seems a lot of people are of the opinion that we should load javascripts on a page-by-page basis (I gather this from people's answers with regards to rails asset pipeline questions to that effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the one thing that you are not really talking about in this with regards to performance is actual HTML browser download behavior. I believe you have to walk a fine line between only displaying the javascript needed on a page by page basis and leveraging browser caching and download behavior.

For example, say you have 20 different javascript snippets that are going to be used on every page.  In this case it is a no-brainer to compile/minify them into a single file, as the fewer files your browser needs to download, the better. This single file would also be able to be cached, that is assuming it is a static file or appearing to be static (via headers sent) if it is dynamically compiled.

Now say of those 20 snippets, 15 are used on every page and the others are used intermittently.  Of course you put all 15 of the always used snippets into a single file. But what about the others?  In my opinion you need to consider the size and frequency of use of the files.  If they are small and used relatively frequently, I might consider putting them into the main file, with the thought that the extra size in the main file is outweighed by the need to have additional request to download the content later.  If the code is large, I would tend to only use it where necessary. Of course once it is used, it should remain in cache.

This approach might best be suited for a web application where users are expect to typically have multiple page loads per session.  Of course if you are designing an advertising landing pages or seomthing where the user only may see that single page, you might lean on keeping the initial javasciprt download as small as possible and only loading new javascript in as necessary based on user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Every aspect of this question boils down to "it depends".

Are you writing an enterprise-level application, which results in 80,000 lines of code, when you stuff it all together?

If so, then yes, compilation time is going to be huge, and if you stuff that in the `<head>` of your document, people are going to feel the wait time.
Even if it's already cached, compile time alone will be palpable.

Are you writing dozens of widgets which might never be seen by an end-user?
Especially on mobile?

If so, then you might want to save them the download/compile time, and instead load your core functionality, and then load extra functionality on-demand, as more studies are showing that the non-technical end-user expects their mobile-internet experience to be similar to their desktop experience, not only in terms of content, but in general wait-times.

Fewer and fewer people are willing to accept 5s-8s for a mobile experience (or a desktop experience on mobile) to get to the point of interactivity, just based on the "well, it's mobile, so it'll take longer" train of thought.

So again, if you've got an 80,000 line application, or a 300kB JS file, or are doing a whole lot of XML parsing, et cetera, prior to load, without offering a separate mobile experience, your stats on mobile are bound to hurt -- especially if you're a media site or a commercial/retail site.

So the correct answer to your question is to say that there is no correct answer to your question, excepting that there are good ideas and bad ideas, based on the target-devices, the intent of the site/application, the demographic, the code-base, the anticipation that users will frequent the site (and thus benefit from cached assets), the frequency of updates to the codebase (having one updated module, with 20 cached modules, versus a fully-invalid 21-module chunk, due to one updated line, with a client-base of 250,000 customers, is a consideration for several reasons)...

...and more...

Figure out what you're doing.
Figure out what you need to do to make that happen.
Figure out how to do it, while providing your customers a good experience.

Know how to combine files.
Know how to load on demand.
Know how to build a light bootstrap, which can intelligently load modules (and/or learn require/AMD).
Use these as ***tools*** to offer your users the best experience possible, given what you're trying to accomplish.