# Only want javascript to execute on a specific Rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I've got some coffee script in `/assets/javascripts/transactions.coffee` that populates a text field (in `/views/transactions/_form.html.erb`) with today's date in `dd/mm/yy` format.

```
$ ->
    today = new Date
    dd = today.getDate()
    mm = today.getMonth() + 1
    #January is 0!
    yyyy = today.getFullYear()
    if dd < 10
      dd = '0' + dd
    if mm < 10
      mm = '0' + mm
    today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy
    $('#transaction_date').val today

$ ->
    $('#transaction_date').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"})
```

Currently, that form is referenced in `/views/transactions/new.html.erb` and `/views/transactions/edit.html.erb`. However, I only want the text field to be populated on `new.html.erb` and not `edit.html.erb`.

What's the 'cleanest' way to achieve this in Rails (4.2.5)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to add page specific javascript in a Rails 3 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437585/best-way-to-add-page-specific-javascript-in-a-rails-3-app)

Comment: @guiniveretoo I've added the version number (4.2.5). I'm hoping there's a better way to achieve this.

Comment: there are 9 answers on that duplicate question. Have you tried all of them? What qualifies a new solution as being better? Edit your question to clarify why those solutions aren't acceptable or why your question isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create functions in `transactions.coffee` that you call from your view with an inline script. For example, in `transactions.coffee`

```
this.App || (this.App = {})
this.App.Transactions =
    runForNewView: () ->
        today = new Date
        dd = today.getDate()
        mm = today.getMonth() + 1
        #January is 0!
        yyyy = today.getFullYear()
        if dd < 10
          dd = '0' + dd
        if mm < 10
          mm = '0' + mm
        today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy
        $('#transaction_date').val today
```

Then for example in the new view template, you would just add

```
<script text="text/javascript">
    $(function() { App.Transactions.runForNewView(); });
</script>
```