# jQuery detect if on home page using Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I detect if I am currently on my home page?
For example, I only want this JS to execute if I am on my landing page, which is:

app/views/pages/home.html.erb

Is there a way to write this in rails like root_path?

Here's my Javascript:

```
var landingPage = root_path; // What should this variable here be?

function updateNavStyle() {
  if(landingPage.length == 0 || location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(landingPage.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    var offset = $('#change_color').offset();
    var scroll_start = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
      // the white normal navbar
      $(".navbar-add").removeClass("navbar-trans");
      $(".navbar-link-text").removeClass("navbar-link-white");
    } else {
      // what the users sees when he lands on the page
      $(".navbar-add").addClass("navbar-trans");
      $(".navbar-link-text").addClass("navbar-link-white");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just have a `<script>updateNavStyle()</script>` located only on your landing page?  Meaning the function could exist statically in your resources for all pages, but only on your landing page would it be invoked.

Comment: Because I tried doing it this way but its not working like when I write this seperately

Comment: Then I would think the question should be more revolving around figuring out why that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

if you using javascript you can check each page load by checking turbolinks:load event and check "class name" that generated automatically by rails constructed from controller and method

below is sample for example if rails load post controller with edit method

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  if ($(".posts.edit")[0] == true) {
    return something;
  }
});
```

and here is if coffeescript sample

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  if $(".posts.edit")[0]
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= javascript_include_tag "my_javascipt_file" %>`

add this to bottom of your

app/views/pages/home.html.erb

more you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437585/best-way-to-add-page-specific-javascript-in-a-rails-3-app)

or just put the script in

app/views/pages/home.html.erb

with script tag of course `<script>your jquery code </script>`